# How to make webpack run eslint and less tasks on file save?

Tags: webpack, eslint

I'm trying to implement webpack into my ReactJS project. Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/main.js",
  output: {
    path: "./dist",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: "./dist"
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "eslint-loader"
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    plugins: ["react"],
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 6,
      sourceType: "module",
      ecmaFeatures: {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    env: {
      es6: true,
      browser: true
    },
    rules: {
      quotes: 0
    }
  }
};
```

Now, on save, my browser reloads, which is a nice built-in feature of Webpack. But I can't make it run the ESLint tests upon save as well.

Also - I'm planning to implement some unit testing and less-to-css compilation, also happening on file save. That's why I decided to see how such things are done, and to try such automatic feature with ESLint ... but still no success.